# Inequalities between three random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a doubt about the following fact

Let $r, s$ and $t$ be numbers such that is valid $1>r>s>t>0$. Let be $(U_n)$ a succession of random variables such that $U_n$ ~ $Unif(0,1) $ and

$X_n = \mathbb{1}_{(U_n<r)}$, $Y_n = \mathbb{1}_{(U_n<s)}$ and $Z_n = \mathbb{1}_{(U_n<t)}$.

Can I say that for each $n$ is valid $X_n \ge Y_n \ge Z_n$?

From the definition of $X_n, Y_n$ and $Z_n$ I would say that the answer to the question is yes.

But I also know that $X_n$ ~ $Bern(r)$, $Y_n$ ~ $Bern(s)$ and $Z_n$ ~ $Bern(t)$ and this would make me conclude that the answer to the previous question is no.

Thank you in advance for your clarifications.

EDIT: $(U_n)$ are IID.

Comment: Recall that `$X_n \ge Y_n \ge Z_n$ is valid' is an event, and you cannot declare that this is true, you can only ascribe a probability of this being true. Usually, we tend to say that a statement about random variables (like '$X \ge Y$ is valid') is true if it holds with probability $1$ (the technical term used is that the statement is true *almost surely*), but in this case it is quite clear that $P(X_n \ge Y_n \ge Z_n) < 1$ as you seem to have concluded already.

Comment: Maybe in the question I did not express myself well. So are the following statements both false? 1) $X_n \ge Y_n$ almost surely; 2) $X_n \ge Y_n$ as functions (so that each value that $X_n$ assumes is greater than each value that $Y_n$).

Comment: Oh, oops, I was wrong in that the probability under question is <1 (I missed that $X,Y,Z$ were defined with respect to the same drawing of $U$). My apologies for any confusion I might have caused. In particular, in your case, the statement does hold surely. The idea is that while the marginal densities of the variables is indeed Bernoulli as you mentioned, they are not independent, and since $U<s \implies U< r,$ $X \ge Y$ always.

Comment: I have to apologize, for my mistake I did not write that $U_n$ are IID. Sorry again.

Comment: 90% of words in your question aren't needed: if $s\le t$, then $1_{x<s}\le  1_{x<t} $. Everything else is irrelevant: randomness, distributions, independence.